# Design View in Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET 4.0 not keeping HTML format, (it gets a mess)

Tags: asp.net, c, visual-studio-2010

I have an issue with my design view in asp.net. I have a master Page which when I debug eerything is fine but when I choose design view in the window al controls are missplaced.

Any idea how to fix this? Again when debuging with Chrome, IE9, Firefox the page shows just well.

Thank you :D
Screenshot

http://i49.tinypic.com/2n9j7r.png

Comment: Sadly thats quite normal afaik - I used to treat the designer as a general guide many years ago (around vs2002) but since they introduced the Code only view I just use that and don't use the designer at all.

Comment: OKay, I see. I thought there were some settings to change in the HTML view on the opions. But well well. I see the positive side, learing to manipulate the source code :)

Comment: Once you switch to source code you willl not miss the designer and youll never look back. Also if you switch to code only view youll get more screen space!